# What will be the interval of convergence $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(n+1)^2 x^n}{n^n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

So do I have to check $$ \lim_{n\to\infty}  \frac{(n+1)^2 }{n^n}$$  I think that I don't have to use, the absolute value,because for every $n$ will be positive. How can I continue it?

Comment: The limit is clearly zero. But this is only a necessary condition for convergence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it is a power series (do you know power series?), it is almost enough to compute
$$
\frac{1}{L}=\lim_{n \to +\infty} \sqrt[n]{\frac{(n+1)^2}{n^n}} = \lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{\sqrt[n]{(n+1)^2}}{n}.
$$
The series will converge in $(-L,L)$. You should finally analyze the convergence when $x=-L$ and $x=L$.
Please remark that $L=\infty$ if the previous limit is zero, and $L=0$ if the limit is infinite.

Comment: and what if the limit is zero? so, $ x=0$

Comment: It is convenient to take $L=+\infty$ in this case.

Comment: and if it would be an other number,in this case, I should check $(-L,L)$

Comment: The theory already says that the power series convergence in $(-L,L)$, you do not need to check this every time.